# Just can't import files to my Racket program

Tags: prolog, scheme, racket

One in two files I try to import to my program doesn't work out.
I know the programs have to be in the same folder or at least the command require must state the directory.
I've got a folder where my program is saved and a folder se3-bib in the same folder that my program is in.
Then, there's another folder in the se3-bib folder called prolog which contains a file I'd like to import to my program.

When I try this:

```
#lang racket
(require  "se3-bib/prolog/prologInScheme.rkt")
```

I get a fail saying:

```
se3-bib\prolog\prologInScheme.rkt:19:3: standard-module-name-resolver: collection not found
  for module path: se3-bib/tools-module
  collection: "se3-bib"
  in collection directories:
   C:\Users\Lidiya\AppData\Roaming\Racket\6.3\collects
   C:\Users\Lidiya\Documents\Mathe WS1516\SE3\Racket\collects
   ... [161 additional linked and package directories] in: se3-bib/tools-module
  no packages suggestions are available
```

You can also find a [screenshot of that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kjp8S.png).

Comment: That error you’re getting is in the other file (`prologInScheme.rkt`) on line 19. You can tell that because the path at the beginning of the error message mentions the location is in that file. Look there to find the problem.

Comment: thanks, I found the problem but I still can't fix it because the files I'd like to import aren't mine but provided by my professor..

Comment: can you tell me whether there's a difference between saying

Comment: require "se3-bib/prolog.rkt" and require se3-bib/prolog?

Comment: Yes, there is. When you use a string, like `"se3-bib/prolog.rkt"`, then that is a reference to a local file with a relative path. When you use a bare symbol, like `se3-bib/prolog`, that is a reference to a Racket library that is installed on the system. Module paths exist in a global namespace that do not necessarily directly correspond to the filesystem.

Comment: Do you have the se3-bib directory installed as a package? To do that, you can go to the File menu in DrRacket, click package manager, click browse, and then select the se3-bib directory. Does that fix it?

Comment: yes, thank you very much, it's working out now!